# Trying to center contents via PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to center justify below image post thumbnails automatically with PHP.

Including picture and present PHP code. I have taken a crack at it and failing terribly, my PHP skills are mediocre at best and any help on this will be much appreciated.

[image]

```js
<?php  $count = 1; 
$settings  = _WSH()->option();
$query_args = array('post_type' => 'sh_services' , 'showposts' => $num , 'order_by' => $sort , 'order' => $order);

if( $cat ) $query_args['services_category'] = $cat;
$query = new WP_Query($query_args) ; 
$top_heading_img= get_template_directory_uri()."/images/head-top.png";
$top_heading_img = sh_set( $settings, 'top_heading_img' ) ? sh_set( $settings, 'top_heading_img' ) : $top_heading_img;
//printr($top_heading_img);

ob_start() ;?>

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ):?>

 <!--======= SERVICES =========-->
 <section class="services">
  <div class="container"> 

   <!--======= TITTLE =========-->
   <div class="tittle"> <img src="<?php  echo $top_heading_img;  ?>" alt="">
    <h3><?php echo balanceTags($title);?></h3>
    <p><?php echo balanceTags($text);?></p>
   </div>
   <ul class="row">

    <?php while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
    global $post ;
    $services_meta = _WSH()->get_meta(); 
    ?>

    <!--======= SERVICE SECTION =========-->
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
     <section> 
      <!--======= SERVICE IMG =========--> 
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('271x337', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));?>
      <div class="icon"> <img src="<?php echo sh_set($services_meta, 'small_image');?>" alt="image"> </div>

      <!--======= SERVICE HOVER =========-->
      <div class="ser-hover">
       <p><?php echo _sh_trim(get_the_content(), $text_limit);?> <a href="<?php echo sh_set($services_meta, 'readmore_link');?>" class="read-more"><?php esc_html_e('Read more ', 'realtor');?><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a> </p>
      </div>
      <a href="<?php echo sh_set($services_meta, 'readmore_link');?>" class="heading"><?php the_title();?></a> </section>
     </li>

    <?php endwhile;?>

   </ul>
  </div>
 </section>

<?php endif;?>  
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
return ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: This isn't a PHP skill. It's a HTML/CSS skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what I wanted had to change column class to col-sm-4 then reduce row width to 900px and finally set margin left & right to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of bootstrap you are using you can use either below

V4+

```
class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
```

V3

```
class="img-responsive center-block"
```

but as stated this is a CSS question, not PHP

Comment: Technically correct not php but CSS being added to php file. Sorry for incorrect etiquette. I am not a professional just a hack. Could you shed light where in the code I should add the above class. Replace the class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" with above?

Comment: no, add this class to the image you want to center.